# How to save data in a model

Tags: python-3.x, django

I am attempting to save `Total_Amount` in a model.

****Views****

```
def Booking(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
           form = Bookingform(request.POST)
           if form.is_valid():
               a = form.save()
               print(form.data["Number_of_Persons"])
               Number_of_Persons = int(form.data["Number_of_Persons"])
               Total_Amount = (Number_of_Persons * 100)
               print(Total_Amount)
               a = Booking(Number_of_Persons=Number_of_Persons, Total_Amount=Total_Amount)
               a.save()
               return HttpResponse(str(Total_Amount))
        else:
            form = Bookingform()
    return render(request, 'ticketbooking.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Please clarify what it is you are trying to do and what problems you are having

Comment: Please add the model `Booking` and the form `Bookingform` to your question.